# Callback function in for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, callback

How do I get a function to run after all the fadeOuts in the for loop below?

What I need to do is fadeout anything that may be visible and then fadein a specific object. Due to styling requirements my topnav and dropdown nav are in to different uls which is why things are tricky.

I'm not very good at writing my own scripts yet so I'm (hopefully) missing something basic.

I've tried wrapping things in functions but that seems to mess with variable scope and screws things up that I don't understand...

Thanks for any help!

```
$('.ksddtop').on('mouseenter', function(){
    var ddtop = $(this).text();
    var dd = $('.' + ddtop);
    $('.ksddwrap').fadeIn();
    $(dd).fadeIn();

    var ksdds = $('.ksdd');
    for(var i = 0; i < ksdds.length; i++) {
        var ksdd = ksdds[i];
        if (! $(ksdd).hasClass(ddtop) ){
            $(ksdd).fadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it, if I understand the requirements:

```
$('.ksdd:not(' + ddtop + ')').fadeOut().promise().done(function(){
    // all done fading!
});
```

Fade out all `ksdd` elements that don't have the `ddtop` class, then do something when they are all done animating.

More Information:

calling `.promise` on a jQuery collection gives you a promise object that will resolve when all animations on the collection of elements are complete. This includes queued animations.

If you instead passed a callback function directly to `.fadeOut()`, you would get a callback *for each element* rather than one after they were all done.

Comment: Yes! This works beautifully! Can you explain why this works? What the promise() function is (looking at it it the jquery docs now...)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the added info! promise() was exactly what I needed! Great to have that one in the tool chest now!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var ksdds = $('.ksdd');
for(var i = 0; i < ksdds.length; i++) {
    var ksdd = ksdds[i];
    if (! $(ksdd).hasClass(ddtop) ){
        $(ksdd).fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Try:

```
$('.ksdd').each(function(){
    if (! $(this).hasClass(ddtop) ){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    }
});
```